# JS - Unhandled promise

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, promise, node-mssql

I created a node.js web application. Currently I'm using MSSQL for the DB. I added the [node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connections-1) package. I created functions, in a separate file called ***sql.js***, to perform the corresponding SQL functions. The ***controller.js*** calls them with the await keyword. I had no errors when i was make one request at a time, but if two request come in around the same time i get the following error.

> (node:136648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: error is not defined
>   (node:136648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I think i has something to do with the connection, im using a global one, but i debugged my ***controller.js*** and saw that pool was defined, so im unsure what is causing the issue.

SQL.js

```
const sql = require('mssql'); 
const config = {
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'linux',
    server: '11.222.33.44',
    database: 'master'
}
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config); 
pool.on('error', err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('sql errors', err);
    }
    if (!err) {
        pool.connect();
    }
});
module.exports.getUsers = async() => {
    // const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    try{
        const result  = await pool.request()
            .query(`SELECT * FROM master.dbo.users ORDER BY user_id`)
        // sql.close();
        return result.recordset; 
    }catch(err){
        throw error; 
    }
}
module.exports.getProducts = async() => {
    // const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    try{
        const result  = await pool.request()
            .query(`SELECT * FROM master.dbo.products ORDER BY product_zip`)
        // sql.close();
        return result.recordset; 
    }catch(err){
        throw error; 
    }
}
```

controller.js

```
const express = require('express');
const {getInfo, getUsers, getProducts} = require('../lib/sql');
const router = express.Router();

...

/// Get Users
router.get('/controller/getUsers', async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('get: /controller/getUsers'); 
    const users = await getUsers(); 
    res.status(200).json(users);   
});
/// Get Products
router.get('/controller/getProducts', async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('get: /controller/getProducts'); 
    const products = await getProducts(); 
    res.status(200).json(products);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `catch(err){ throw error; }` `error` is not defined because your parameter name is `err`

Comment: Also, FWIW, catching an error and just immediately throwing it again is pretty pointless. If you're not going to do anything else inside `catch`, just omit the `try..catch` entirely.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: That's quite true, but that will only be a problem during `catch` handling, and even without that typo the problem will still occur if a promise is rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error handling in your various `router.get` callbacks, and `router.get` doesn't do anything with the *return value* of the function you pass it, so if you pass it an `async` function, the promise that function returns will not be handled, and for *rejected* promises, that's an unhandled error. Hence the error message.

Instead: You have to handle errors. For instance:

```
router.get('/controller/getUsers', async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log('get: /controller/getUsers'); 
        const users = await getUsers(); 
        res.status(200).json(templates);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(/*...*/);
    }
});
```

That still returns a promise that's never handled, but at least it never *rejects* (assuming nothing in the `catch` code fails).

If you have a common way of returning errors, you probably want to give yourself a wrapper function around `router.get` (and such) that handles errors from the callbacks so that's nicely centralized.

For instance:

```
const asyncRouterGet = (route, handler) => {
    return router.get(route, (req, res, next) => {
        handler(req, res, next)
        .catch(err => {
            // Common error handling here
            res.status(500).send(/*...*/);
        });
    });
};
```

then

```
asyncRouterGet('/controller/getUsers', async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('get: /controller/getUsers'); 
    const users = await getUsers(); 
    res.status(200).json(templates);
});
```

...since you know rejections will be automatically handled by `asyncRouterGet`'s generated callback.

---

And obviously, don't do this:

```
try {
    // ...
}
catch (err) {
    throw error;
}
```

`error` isn't defined anywhere in your quoted code, and

```
try {
    // ...
}
catch (err) {
    throw err;
}
```

would be pointless; just leave the `try`/`catch` off if you're going to rethrow without doing anything else.

Comment: Yeah, the unhanded promise error was caused by no error handling. Now i got to solve the actual issue.

Comment: @John: :-) As always. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you,  your help was very useful.